# Error when using linux grep command in java

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to get the output of grep linux shell command in java by using process builder. But i got a stuck in this case. Please help me.
Thank in advice!

```
    String[] args = new String[7];
    args[0] = "/bin/bash";
    args[1] = "-c";
    args[2] = "grep";
    args[3] = "-n";
    args[4] = "-e";
    args[5] = "KERNELVERSION";
    args[6] = kernelFilePath.trim();

ProcessBuilder pb;
    Process process = null;
    try {
        pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
        pb = pb.directory(new File(directory));
        pb.inheritIO();
        pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        process = pb.start();
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("executeCmdWithOutput() exception : " + e.toString());
    } finally {
        if (process != null) {
            process.destroy();
        }
    }
```

==> Error:

> Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
>
> Try 'grep --help' for more information.

I tried the command in bash and it worked fine:

```
grep -n -e KERNELVERSION ..../Makefile
```

Comment: Full command must be passed as single argument to bash: `args[2] = "grep -n -e KERNELVERSION " + kernelFilePath.trim();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly run `/bin/bash` in order to execute the `grep` process. Just call it directly and `ProcessBuilder` will run it:

```
String[] args = {"grep", "-n", "KERNELVERSION", kernelFilePath.trim()};
```

Also, you don't need to use the `-e` option, unless there are multiple patterns that you are searching for.

If you really wanted to run `grep` in `/bin/bash`:

```
String[] args = {"/bin/bash", "-c", "grep -n KERNELVERSION " + kernelFilePath.trim()};
```

passes a single argument to `bash` containing the full command and arguments to execute.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried change the args[2] as full command?

Also, you can use pgrep, it does not require you to use pipe.

Comment: How will [`pgrep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) help? It is for grepping for running processes, not for data in a file.